# Angular JS: Set partial form field value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, user-input

I've received an odd request.

The client would like to have the country code of a phone number pre-populated in the "phone" field in the form.  Easy enough to do with `ng-model="0 33 "`...

[image]

except when a user *tabs* into the field, the entire contents will be selected, and overtyped.

can anyone think of a way to set it up so tabbing into the field will simply place the insertion point **after** the already-existing contents from the `ng-model` when the user tabs into the field, so the user can simply continue typing the phone number?

So that it would be like `0 33 |`

Comment: what do you mean by overtyped ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the cursor to the end of the input using:

```
onfocus="this.value = this.value;"
```

Example:

```js
var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);

app.controller("testCtrl", function ($scope) { 
  $scope.foo = "0 33 ";   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="TestApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <input ng-model="foo" onfocus="this.value = this.value;" />
</div>
```